# Coffeescript and ReactJS documentation

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs

I'm searching for a tool to generate documentation for coffeescript AND reactJS both together.

I found multiple things for JavaScript, ReactJS or CoffeeScript (eg: codo).

I'm also using brunch to glue files and to use exported modules in separated files. Codo is very good but seems not really adapted for exported module and ReactJS.

Before going futher and after searching existing tools. Does someone knows a magic wand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it seems that nothing exists. Thus I built one very naive implementation here.

https://github.com/kursion/broffeact